# How to let clang-format do not format simple enum into a single line?

Tags: coding-style, clang, llvm, clang-format

Snippet 1:

```
enum {
  Test
};
```

Snippet 2:

```
enum { Test };
```

In llvm 4.3.2, clang-format will format `Snippet 2` into `Snippet 1`, but in llvm 4.5.0 and above, clang-format does the opposite thing, which means it would format `Snippet 1` into `Snippet 2`.

Both version use the same format option, `-style=google`.

How to control this behavior using `.clang-format` file? I have tried a lot of options mentioned in clang-format doc, but none of them work.

Answer (score 1):

In the [documentation](https://clang.llvm.org/docs/ClangFormatStyleOptions.html) for Clang 12 (not yet released, I believe), there is a new style option `AllowShortEnumsOnASingleLine` which should directly control this. Set to `false` for Snippet 1, or `true` for Snippet 2.

Until then, I don't think you can get the Snippet 1 formatting. The closest you can get is to set `BreakBeforeBraces: Allman`, or (equivalently) set `BreakBeforeBraces: Custom` and set the `BraceWrapping` flag `AfterEnum: true`. This would give you:

```
enum
{
  Test
};
```